# Get specific content from div from another site using jQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, cross-domain

I need to get `#Menu` `div` portion of a site in a different domain through jQuery into my `#menu` in my current site. I am using `$(#menu).load(www.example.com/index.html #menu);` . I am getting permissions denied error. any suggestions?

Comment: It will depends on whether CORS support is enabled in the target domain

Comment: U must store the html into a var then use find to find this variable

Comment: @pete Thanks dude let me check these suggestions and see, this may take some time.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I will check CORS support, its just that time is what i dont have